# When launching firefox, it does not show in applications but is showing in processes

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

I am running a Windows 7 x64 system.  Over the last few weeks Firefox Version 40.0 will only launch the first time.  After exiting, the next time I launch it it will not show anything on the screen.

- Firefox is not showing as running on the taskbar.
- Checking the task manager, Firefox does not show under Applications
- Firefox DOES show up under processes.

Ending the process and relaunching Firefox results in the same issue.

Restarting my system is the only way to get Firefox to launch again, and again, it will only work once.

Firefox will start in Safe Mode.

Things I have tried:

- Disabling all add-ons, extensions, etc.
- Logging out of my sync profile and creating a new one
- Uninstalled Firefox via Windows uninstall programs and then reinstalling
- Doing a "clean" install, meaning the C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox folder is deleted in its entirety and then Firefox is reinstalled.

I am completely stumped.  As a side note, I also run Firefox Developer and it is giving me no problems and it has been installed and working fine with Firefox before this current issue started.

I do need the Firefox traditional browser as I develop and I need it as part of cross browser testing.

Anyone have any things to try that I have not already?

You help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to remove user profile data after uninstalled Firefox via Windows uninstall program? if haven't please check http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_Firefox at removing user data profile section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Firefox version 41.0 resolved the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I have a bit similar problem, but *downgrading* actually helped me. ([details](http://superuser.com/questions/1032737/firefox-44-will-not-start-on-my-windows-7))

Comment: I'd love to comment on your thread, but I don't have the reputation.  This problem has recently cropped up again both in FF 43.0.4 and FF Developer Edition under Windows 7.  Rebooting is the only way I get them back and then the second I exit either one, the one exited will not open again.  Tried all the things on your thread.