# Firefox 44 will not start on my Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

The problem is, Firefox window will not open when I try to start it. I can only see a process appear in the task manager, but no window will show up. It used to work fine but something, possibly an update, has broke it. Using Windows 7, Firefox 44.

Things I've tried:

- Start it in safe mode with shift pressed: no impact, same behavior
- Try to start profile manager using firefox.com -P: no impact, same behavior
- Try to remove the binaries from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox and reinstalling: no impact, same behavior when starting
- Uninstalled Firefox using its own installer, then reinstalled: no impact
- Removed my profile from C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles: no impact, same behavior when starting
- Removed my profile from C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles: on first run after this complained about missing profile; reinstalling Firefox brought back to error behavior
- Rebooted the computer: no impact
- Run a Microsoft Security Essentials scan: no results
- Checked for results in Event Viewer -> Applications, nothing interesting
- chkdsk found no problems

After each test, I've also killed the firefox.exe process using task manager before trying something else.

I'm at loss. I have no more ideas what to try.

---

Edit: I've now [opened a bug to bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1243914) about this, as it seems to be an actual bug.

---

Edit 2: I should have mentioned that I've been using 32-bit version of Firefox on my 64-bit Windows 7. Switching to 64-bit Firefox also made the issue go away.

So as a summary, the problem seems to be that since Firefox 44, running 32-bit version of Firefox on 64-bit Windows 7 seems to work only if you run it as Administrator.

---

Edit 3: now the problem has had an interesting twist to it. [My bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1243914) has been closed, as according to them now that [Firefox has released a 64-bit version of the browser](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/), I should have just switched to that and by continuing the use of 32-bit version of Firefox this is expected. Because currently the default upgrade path will not switch to 64-bit, this would lead to hangs on any user not heard of 64-bit version, which is probably a lot of people. You are expected to "just know" that you need to switch to another version manually by uninstalling and going directly to the site to download a 64-bit version.

---

Edit 4: bug re-opened, we're working on it.

Comment: What software or updates have been installed recently and before this problem started to happen?

Comment: Have you attempted to use System Restore to go back to a date it was working? Have you uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox? Are there any error messages in Event Viewer? Is the system clean of viruses and malware?

Comment: I haven't installed any software in a while, if you mean firefox extensions or plugins. The firefox version I tried installing (from scratch) was 44.0 (us-en).

Comment: @CharlieRB I did remove the binaries from program files and reinstall it. (third bullet point) System restore I've yet to try.

Comment: Only recent events in event viewer, applications section is two entries by "RestartManager", I assume from the time I restarted my computer.

Comment: Running malware/virus checks right now, just in case.

Comment: "no problems detected".

Comment: Using just MSE really isn't enough to verify you have no malware.  Does any other browser work?  Does Firefox 43 work?

Comment: other browsers and other applications work just fine. haven't tried yet the previous version.

Comment: wow. using previous version and firefox -P, I was able to get profile manager to start up, then delete previous profile and create a new one.

Comment: but again, if I go through the about dialog and select an update, it will first update from 43 to 43.0.1 just fine, then the next update (I assume 44) will lead back to problematic behavior.

Comment: I was even able to get my old profile working (I copied it elsewhere just to be safe before deleting) by copying it back. If you want to add an answer about downgrading Firefox, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Have you checked if the window is just completely off-screen?

Comment: @KarmaEDV if it were off-screen, I could see it still in applications list. Now only process shows up.

Comment: Not reproducible here. No problems running Firefox 44.0 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Have you tried installing as an Administrator?

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed, installing or running as administrator seems to also fix the issue. That is not needed when I am using Firefox 43.

Comment: @eis I suggest you add that to your bug report. It will help the devs find the underlying issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill already did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem after updating to Firefox 44.
The first launch is successful, but after closing that, Firefox does not start even if system has been restarted.
Also Firefox does not open when clicking links in others programs (i.e. messenger). Firefox has a process running, but it does not open a window.

I solved the problem by installing the latest stable version 43. 
https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/43.0.4/

We need to wait and hope that they will fix it in the next version.

Comment: As a comment, I would say I managed to launch Firefox 44 when executing as an admin.

Comment: @RaphPetrini for me as well.